# Put Options with strikes 30 and 20 on the same asset with same maturity are trading for $6 and $4 respectively. Can you find an arbitrage?

Tags: put-options

New to finance questions and reading from *150 Most Frequently Asked Questions on Quant Interviews.* In the solutions section of this book, it says:

*In the plane (K,P(K)) the options values correspond to the points (30,6), (20,4), and (0,0) which are on the line P(K) = (2/3)K.*

I feel like I am missing something obvious about the problem, because all three of those points lie on the line P(K) = (1/5)K. It looks like 2/3 of point one gives point two but that is not equivalent.

Does anyone have any insight? Thank you!

Comment: The 2/3 is a typo and should be 1/5 as you correctly wrote. The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112095) and is based on strict convexity of the call option price as a function of strike.

Comment: Thanks AKdemy! thought I was going crazy